# Can my ISP or government listen to my Skype calls?

Tags: encryption, privacy, tcp, udp, skype

Is the call encrypted with something like HTTPS to prevent a corrupt government (or ISP) from messing with the DNS routing, sniffing, snooping etc? Can my ISP or government listen to my Skype calls?

I'm calling a bank's 800 number from Skype using my phone while being present in a random country.

By government, I'm referring to the government of the country I'm in. Not US. I assume they can listen to any iPhone or Android phone whenever they want.

Comment: Maybe not any government directly, but Microsoft can, and does, according to this Article: https://www.heise.de/security/meldung/Vorsicht-beim-Skypen-Microsoft-liest-mit-1857620.html (German, and some years old). So, if the government in question can compel Microsoft to disclose contents, the answer would be yes.

Comment: I'm ok with Microsoft listening my calls. Your comment is irrelevant. I'm asking a question about networking and encryption fundamentals.

Comment: @Marcel is right, your government can not listen on real time your conversation because they dont have the keys for decrypt that communication, but your government can ask microsoft for that information and depending on legal stuff they can intercept your communications and then deliver to your government.

Comment: @user274772 Nowhere in your question I read about technical stuff like networking and encryption cyphers used. If that is your real question, I suggest you reword it to say so.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your question is about making a phone call through Skype, as opposed to actual Skype calls. In other words, your bank doesn't use Skype, but you can still call them using their phone number.

If I got this part right, they number is yes — your government can technically listen to your call. Phone calls are not encrypted and intercepting a phone call is trivially easy for a government agency.

Whether they do is another question — it depends on where you live, what are the applicable laws, are you a high target, etc., but technically it is 100% doable.

This is why you should use encrypted messing apps to call people and avoid phone calls as much as possible.

Actual Skype calls can be encrypted, but you have to call somebody from within [a private conversation](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34824/what-are-skype-private-conversations).